# Slide toggle DIV from right to left

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

I am trying to slide a DIV from right to left over another DIV. It works for the initial slide over, but it's the slide back that isn't working. It slides back right to left again to disappear, then I try to click the button again but it won't work after first open and close.

My code to follow:

```
function changeFeat () {
    if(jQuery('#featartinside').css('display') == 'none') {
        jQuery('#featartinside').animate({
            width: 730,
            marginLeft: 1,
            marginRight: -730,
            display: 'toggle'
        }, 'slow');
    } else {
        jQuery('#featartinside').animate({
            width: -730,
            marginLeft: 1,
            marginRight: 730,
            display: 'toggle'
        }, 'slow');
    }
}

#featartban {
    position: relative;
    background: url(../images/featart.png) top left no-repeat;
    width: 54px;
    height: 279px;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
    left: 730px;
    margin-bottom: -279px;
}

#featartinside {
    height: 279px;
    width: 0;
    margin-left: 730px;
    background: #D13630;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: -279px;
}
```

Like I said it works fine for opening, it's the closing that isn't working since it continues right to left instead of closing left to right. Then I can't get a second open and close.

EDIT HTML:

```
<div id="featartban" onclick="changeFeat(); return false;"></div>
<div id="featartinside" style="display: none;"></div>
```

Comment: It's 2 lines ha ha :) Done.

Comment: The problem I am seeing is once you collapse the inside div, it is keeping a display type of "block".  Thus, not hitting the open code.

Comment: I realize the code may be short, but it was unclear if one was a container of the other, if they were beside each other, etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sticking to jQuery.

```
<div id="featartban"></div>
<div id="featartinside" style="display: none;"></div>​
```

```
var $featartban = $("#featartban");
var $featartinside = $("#featartinside");
$featartban.toggle(function show() {
  $featartinside.animate({
    width: 730,
    marginLeft: 1,
    marginRight: -730,
    display: 'toggle'
  }, 'slow');
}, function hide() {
  $featartinside.animate({
    width: 0,
    marginLeft: 730,
    marginRight: 0,
    display: 'toggle'
  }, 'slow');
});​
```

[`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) (not confuse with [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)) is awesome.

[See it live here.](http://jsfiddle.net/DsUU8/)

Comment: AWESOME! I knew I was missing something. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

JS:

```
/*creating click event*/
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a#click-a').click(function(){
    $('.nav').toggleClass('nav-view');
  });
});
```

Demo : http://www.themeswild.com/read/slide-navigation-left-to-right